# What is step by step process for add products to magento guest cart using Rest apis?

Tags: magento2, api, addtocart

I am trying like this,

Step 1:
Post(empty) `baseurl/rest/V1/guest-carts`

get: `guest customerid =02ccea0d67a4be667fa6ebf7905tia21`

Step 2: I want add items to cart,so am using this api, `POST /V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items`

```
Post: {
"cartItem": {
"itemId": 2,
"sku": "RJ0111",
"qty": 1,
"name": "Normal Kit",
"quoteId": "02ccea0d67a4be667fa6ebf7905tia21",

}
```

`baseurl/rest/V1/guest-carts/02ccea0d67a4be667fa6ebf7905tia21/items`

it gives response as 400 Bad Request,how can i get this and please tell me process step by step.

and what is **"quoteId" here**,

Answer (score 21):

Please follow the below steps as shown in the screenshots so that it will help you

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

1) Mask Key we can trace out from the table called **'quote_id_mask'** 
[image]

2) **quote_id (or) cart id** as well you can check it in the same table

3) cart item info saved in the table called **quote_item**

Comment: This works as expected. a cart is created in the database, i am able to add items to this cart. but: it creates a new guest cart. and the cart is not linked to the current guest customer session. is there a rest api endpoint to use the existing guest customer session cart?

Answer (score 7):

The API is very tricky here.

1. You need to create a cart first:
   `[POST] /V1/carts/`

This will return an ID.

2. Now add the item to your cart:
   `[POST] /V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items`

Body:

```
{
    "cart_item": {
        "quote_id": "{{use_your_cart_id}}",
        "sku": "YOUR_PRODUCT_SKU",
        "qty": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you guys know of a way to get items thumbnails when requesting the cart?

Comment: So {cartId} and the value of "quote_id" should be the same value?  What if they are not?

Comment: @awavi when i run the POST http:/test.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/items
Response: The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources

Answer (score 7):

For guest you need to follow these steps:

**Step-1:** Create empty guest-cart

**POST** **http://yourhost.com/rest/V1/guest-carts**

The response of above request will give you `"cartKey"`

[Note: remove double quotes from the response]. And store it in some area, it will be needed in Step-2.

**Step-2:** Get cart details at any time after Step-1 above,

**GET** **http://yourhost.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/**`{cartKey from step-1}`

**Step-3:** Add product to the cart

**POST** **http://yourhost.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/**`{cartKey from step-1}`**/items**

Submit the JSON Payload

{
    "cartItem" : {
        "sku" : productSKU,
        "qty" : 1,
        "quoteId" : quoteId
    }
 }

**Note:**

1. productSKU = The product you want to add to cart
2. qty=1 means you want to add one product to cart
3. quoteId=quoteId you received in **step-2**

> how can i get this and please tell me process step by step.
>   and what is "quoteId" here,

`quoteId` is the actual cart id in `quote` table. From the response of **Step-2** you can find it in JSON response with key `id`.

Here are the [list of magento 2 APIs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html) listing with modules.