# What are the steps to build native apps for website powered by magento 2.x?

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2, rest-api, app, mobile-device

What are the technical requirements for building android and ios apps for website powered by magento 2.x . I don't have a website ready yet but initial setup with sample data is done i.e luma store. How can we use magento's web services to make apps synchronous with website. I want detailed steps or reference here from where to start. How the website or magento 2 should be configured to work with mobile apps? As of now I know magento provides web services in REST and SOAP criterion. I want to make own native apps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visit earlier questions I answered. They will help you in detail to get start https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106474/what-is-step-by-step-process-for-add-products-to-magento-guest-cart-using-rest-a/151382#151382  and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110026/magento-2-where-does-the-oauth-verifier-token-come-from/151817#151817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have already done with the project which have an intermediate panel which is connected to magento 2.0 using REST web service
The magento web service API can be used for diffrent purpose

So start from Where??

First of all install fresh magento on your server and set it up
You can download fresh magento zip file from here [Link](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)

After setup of magento

Go to admin panel from left menu click navigate to SYSTEM->Extension->Integration
And Add new Integration read doc [Link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/create-integration.html)
For More details on Web API intergration Look into [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108885/what-is-a-magento-2-web-api-integration)

After adding integration 
Create a web api using your programming language  for example i am using PHP for calling web service of magento using CURL

Example Code For Getting All Magento Categories

```
$headers = array("Content-Type:application/json","Authorization: Bearer YOUR_WEB_SHOW_KEY"); //Key Will Be generated at the time of adding integration in magento admin
$requestUrl= 'http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/categories'; //Magento Web Api For Get all Categories
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returnJson = curl_exec($ch); //return the category list in JSON Format
```

You can Also Call another web Apis (REST) for diffrent purpose
from here

[Magento 2.0.*](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html)

[Magento 2.1.*](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_21.html)

[Magento 2.2.*](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_21.html)

Comment: Can you please provide  a link for implementation of rest api? So that I can have  knowledge about it and where to put files and how to test APIs.